# Linking to older version of gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking

I have CentOS 6.2 (64bit with gcc 4.4.6 as default). Unfortunately, my code only compiles with gcc 3.4.6, so I installed gcc separately (from source) under /home/rajat/local. On linking a simple "Hello World" program, I get the following.

```
>ldd a.out 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff215ff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/rajat/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f11853e7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000033be400000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/rajat/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f11851ce000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000033bd000000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000033bcc00000)
```

While stdc++ and gcc link to my 3.4.6 libraries, libm and libc still link to default libraries. Is this OK?? The 3.4.6 installation also did not produce libm or libc libraries?

Comment: That looks like a bad idea; you will need to update your code to compile with more modern compilers.

Comment: @trojanfoe - yes I know its a bad idea. But I have to live with it unfortunately for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's ok.

The libc/libm is part of glibc, not the gcc compiler. libstdc++ on the other hand ls part of gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` as well as their 64-bit counterparts are *system-wide* libraries. They are supposed to be *compiler neutral* and other compilers besides GCC can also link to them and they actually do, especially since `libc` is the only portable way to interface with the operating system kernel.

`libc` writers take great care of writing their header files in such a way as to make different compilers produce the same binary memory objects in order to properly interface with the code in the library. Besides, there is a well-defined OS ABI interface that all compilers adhere to in order to be compatible with one another. This might not be true for languages other than C, e.g. object files from different C++ compiler versions rarely go well with one another.

Compiler-specific libraries are not installed in `/lib` or `/usr/lib` and sometimes can be linked statically so that the dependency can be removed.

Comment: Note that the distro default libstdc++ resides in one of those lib/ folders, yet that library is quite dependent on at least the major versjon of gcc.